# How to mount Android Phone's sdcard to be both visible on PC and Phone?

Tags: android

How to mount Android Phone's sdcard to be both visible on PC and Phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the SD card while debugging using either the 'adb shell' command or using FileExplorer in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

It's not for security, it is because USB mass storage intrinsically can not do this -- when you mount the card, the OS is working at the direct block level, managing the filesystem itself.  Two different machines doing this at the same time would pretty much instantly corrupt your data.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible... well, maybe if you compile a ROM by your self that does what you want.

Comment: So while I debug, I can't view the SDCard contents on the PC as the connection is setup for debuggging and not for disk mount. Too bad.

Comment: Yes... it's that way for security reasons I guess.

Comment: You can't see it from the PC but you can using 'adb shell' etc. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually windows mobile on my Omnia2 allows simultaneous access from the PC as well as on the phone. I guess as long as the proper locking is done when writing to the storage, I don't see why not.